# L is a regular language and w is any word, not necessarily in L. Show that L is regular

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars

$L$ is a regular language and $w$ is any word, not necessarily in $L$. We define the set as

$$L/w = \{x \in \Sigma ^* \mid xw \in L\}.$$

Show that $L/w$ is regular.

I'm really struggling with this one. I know its going to come on my final next week.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to argue with the reflected version of $L$. Do you know that regular languages are closed under reflection? Then argue with the DEA for this language.

Comment: It seems that you peeked at the final, since you already know two questions that are going to appear there.

Comment: Look for questions involving the quotient operation.

Comment: Thanks guys. He gave us a list of 15 possible questions that 'could' be on it and these were the two toughest ones so I assume they will be on it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider a DFA for $L$. Suppose that upon reading $x$, the DFA is at state $s$. Can you predict at which the DFA would be after reading $xw$?